# PHP Counting inside an Array

Tags: php, arrays

I want to create a list where if its already in the array to add to the value +1.

**Current Output**

```
[1] => Array
    (
        [source] => 397
        [value] => 1
    )

[2] => Array
    (
        [source] => 397
        [value] => 1
    )

[3] => Array
    (
        [source] => 1314
        [value] => 1
    )
```

**What I want to Achieve**

```
[1] => Array
    (
        [source] => 397
        [value] => 2
    )

[2] => Array
    (
        [source] => 1314
        [value] => 1
    )
```

**My current dulled down PHP**

```
        foreach ($submissions as $timefix) {

              //Start countng
              $data = array(
                    'source' => $timefix['parent']['id'],
                    'value' => '1'
              );

              $dataJson[] = $data;

    }

            print_r($dataJson);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simply use an associated array:

```
$dataJson = array();

foreach ($submissions as $timefix) {
    $id = $timefix['parent']['id'];

    if (!isset($dataJson[$id])) {
        $dataJson[$id] = array('source' => $id, 'value' => 1);
    } else {
        $dataJson[$id]['value']++;
    }
}

$dataJson = array_values($dataJson); // reset the keys - you don't nessesarily need this
```

Answer (score 1):

This is not exactly your desired output, as the array keys are not preserved, but if it suits you, you could use the item ID as the array key. This would simplify your code to the point of not needing to loop through the already available results:

```
foreach ($submissions as $timefix) {
    $id = $timefix['parent']['id'];
    if (array_key_exists($id, $dataJson)) {
        $dataJson[$id]["value"]++;
    } else {
        $dataJson[$id] = [
            "source" => $id,
            "value" => 1
        ];
    }
}
print_r($dataJson);
```

Answer (score 0):

PHP has a function called `array_count_values` for that. May be you can use it

Example:

```
<?php
$array = array(1, "hello", 1, "world", "hello");
print_r(array_count_values($array));
?>
```

Output:

```
Array
(
    [1] => 2
    [hello] => 2
    [world] => 1
)
```

Answer (score 0):

You should simplify this for yourself. Something like:

```
<?
  $res = Array();
  foreach ($original as $item) {
    if (!isset($res[$item['source']])) $res[$item['source']] = $item['value'];
    else $res[$item['source']] += $item['value'];
  }
?>
```

After this, you will have array `$res` which will be something like:

```
Array(
  [397] => 2,
  [1314] => 1
)
```

Then, if you really need the format specified, you can use something like:

```
<?
  $final = Array();
  foreach ($res as $source=>$value) $final[] = Array(
    'source' => $source,
    'value' => $value
  );
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

This code will do the counting and produce a `$new` array as described in your example.

```
$data = array(
    array('source' => 397, 'value' => 1),
    array('source' => 397, 'value' => 1),
    array('source' => 1314, 'value' => 1),
);

$new = array();
foreach ($data as $item)
{
    $source = $item['source'];
    if (isset($new[$source]))
        $new[$source]['value'] += $item['value'];
    else
        $new[$source] = $item;
}
$new = array_values($new);
```